# Promise argument type is not assignable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

I have the following method on an Angular component class:

```
getPluginViaUrl(url: string): Promise<SCEPluginElement | string> {

    const self = this;

    return fetch(url, {cache: 'no-store'}).then(function (result) {
        return result.text();
      })
      .then(function (code) {

        const result = self.evalPluginCode(code);

        if (!result.SCEPlugin) {
          return Promise.reject('No SCEPlugin property exported from supposed plugin.');
        }

        if (!result.SCEPlugin.pluginName) {
          return Promise.reject('SCEPlugin is missing a name (missing "pluginName" field)');
        }

        if (!result.SCEPlugin.pluginType) {
          return Promise.reject('SCEPlugin is missing a type (missing "pluginType" field).');
        }


        return {
          url: url,
          code: code,
          pluginName: result.SCEPlugin.pluginName,
          pluginType: result.SCEPlugin.pluginType,
          plugin: result.SCEPlugin
        };

      });
  }
```

here is the type being used:

```
export interface SCEPluginElement {
  url: string,
  code: string,
  pluginName: string,
  pluginType: string,
  plugin: Object
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR in src/app/shared/services/utils-service.ts(57,13): error
>   TS2345: Argument of type '(code: string) => Promise | { url:
>   string; code: string; pluginName: any; pluginType: any;...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) =>
>   PromiseLike'.   Type 'Promise | { url: string; code:
>   string; pluginName: any; pluginType: any; plugin: any; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
>       Type '{ url: string; code: string; pluginName: any; pluginType: any; plugin: any; }' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
>         Property 'then' is missing in type '{ url: string; code: string; pluginName: any; pluginType: any; plugin: any; }'.

I cannot figure out what this error means.

Comment: Your callback to then returns either a rejected promise or an object that *isn't* a promise, you need to be more consistent. I guess the typings can't quite handle the fact that returning the object is equivalent to returning a resolved promise of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you are returning `Promise`s for your errors and not `string`s.

I'd suggest replacing all `return new Promise` with `throw new Error`. Then you can use `.catch` to handle the errors and simply return a `SCEPluginElement` instead of `SCEPluginElement | string`.

Comment: funny that `throw 'foo'` doesn't work, but `throw new Error('foo')` does work

Comment: No idea why that is. Personally I always throw `Error`s because other objects don't have a stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know why Promise.reject(x) doesn't work, I think it's a flaw in the type system, because the Promise.reject will resolve to a string...

Comment: Promise typing is flawed. `Promise<x>` should actually take two types. It should be `Promise<x,y>`. One is the type of the resolved value, another is the type of the rejected value. So dumb.